# get next image when I swipe image either Left or Right in android

Tags: android, image, slider, swipe

I am using code from  this link http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/ to make Image Slider.

```
//This method is called each time user swipes the screen
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position)
  {
   TouchImageView imgDisplay;
   imgDisplay = (TouchImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);

   imgDisplay.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        float x1, x2, y1, y2;
        String direction;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {

            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
                x1 = event.getX();
                y1 = event.getY();
                break;
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE): {
                x2 = event.getX();
                y2 = event.getY();
                float differenceInX = x2 - x1;
                float differenceInY = y2 - y1;

                // Use dx and dy to determine the direction
                if (Math.abs(differenceInX) > Math.abs(differenceInY)) {
                    if (differenceInX > 0) {
                        System.out.println("SWIPING RIGHT");
                            Toast.makeText(_activity, "Right",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                     } 
                   else 
                     {
                        System.out.println("SWIPING LEFT "+position);
                            Toast.makeText(_activity, "Left",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                  }
               }

            }
            return false;
        }

    });

     BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
     options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
      //_imagePaths is an arraylist that stores all the image paths.
     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imagePaths.get(position),options);
     imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
  }
```

I have to add the following functionality:

If I swipe the first Image to left I get Second image. But if I swipe the first image to right than also I must get the second Image.

I will make it more clear.

If I swipe the second image to Left side I get third image.

and If I swipe the second image to Right side than also I must get third image instead of first.

Aim is to get next image each time whether I swipe image either to Left or right side.

Comment: you should use gallery widget

Comment: when you swipe it shows image from array of image using adapters position, so create global int count=0; and increment it when you swipe left or right and show image using variable "count" insted of "position"